# What tools are there to list info on a workbook's data-tables and pivot-tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Pivot-tables and data-tables are efficient in analyzing and grouping data in Excel. If you have a few of them in a calculation chain in a workbook it is hard however to get an overview of them, what's in them and how they are linked together.

Are there any tools out there to list what you have in your workbook and how it is linked together? I'm thinking of a tool that lists your tables, their headings, formulas, sizes etc in one place for convenient overwiew.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Deborah Dalgleish' [site](http://www.contextures.com/pivottableindex.html). She has some free tools that you can implement (code) as well as an [add-in](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivotPremAddIn.html) that can be purchased. I don't have the add-in but recall that it offers many of the options you are asking for.

I have used code samples form her site to manage the pivot chaches for example.